# How to add analytics to an Android application with a library in its own process

Tags: android, google-analytics, multiprocessing

I have an Android application which uses Google Analytics. As [recommended by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project), it overrides [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and supplies the class name in its `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

My app relies on a library which contains a service which must run in its own process. Therefore, its `AndroidManifest.xml` has:

```
<application>
    <service
        android:name="org.myservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":myservice">
```

When running, I found that a second, independent instance of `MyApplication` is launched in the library's process. This tries to set up analytics, etc. But the library never asked for this class and doesn't want it.

I tried to declare a different application class in the library's `AndroidManifest.xml` but this causes "Manifest merger failed" build errors.

How can I keep the library process from depending on `MyApplication`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because manifests are merged together, it is only possible to have a single class designated by `android:name` (in either one library or in the main app). One of these objects will be instantiated per process.

My solution is for the Main application class to detect whether the process name matches the APPLICATION_ID. This will only be true for the main process and not for any other.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The print library has its own process but will use this class.
        // Only set up analytics if we are in the main process.
        if (isMainProcess()) {
            // Once-per-app code here
        }
    }

    public boolean isMainProcess() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
            if (processInfo.pid == android.os.Process.myPid()) {
                return TextUtils.equals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                        processInfo.processName);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```